# Use Caldera Forms default instead of retrieved default of form processor for specific inputs

Tags: caldera-forms, form-processor

I came up with a form in Caldera Forms that has some input fields like name, address and an field with name "amount". I'd like to prefill the name and address from civiCRM -- this works. But give the "amount" field a default value specified in Caldera Forms.

When I use the functionality to retrieve defaults for the input fields from civiCRM the "amount" field is also retrieved and filled with the empty string -- as there is no default value in civiCRM (I did not set any default in the form processor "retrieval of defaults" tab in section "set defaults").

What do I overlook here? how can I make the default of Caldera Forms the one to be used?
I have to map the parameter %amount% to the input field "amount" as I want to pass the amount from the form to the form processor.

How can I omit the field "amount" from being filled with "" from form processor's "retrieve defaults" functionality?

Answer (score 0):

not sure to understand your question but it's possible to use different amounts like here in production: https://ffmns.gestad.net/licence/. It has a complex setting but i think that using the contribution processor in Caldera gives you access to these options.